# Visual Studio new Win32 project application doesn't run

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have been learning the basics of Win32 applications, with the aim of building a DirectX11 application, however I have been building very simple Win32 applications in Visual Studio and I have never had a successful execution of the application. The projects will build successfully but the second I click 'Local Windows Debugger' it will appear like its building the project if needed but then nothing happens. Visual Studio just seems to enter an infinite loop, it effectively freezes without being marked as 'not responding'.

Now I now this isn't my code, as even when I create a new Win32 project application with the default settings and build and run it still doesn't work. I have to then forcefully kill the Visual studio application as it never comes back.

I have used visual studio 2013 and 2015 both with the same problem...

I am using Windows 10.

I have checked and all major updates have been installed for both VS versions.

I do have the DirectXSDK installed. Also I have tried this on both my laptop and desktop, of which both are affected.

Any idea what the problem is.... I am unable to run any of my test applications :/

Comment: Are you using Avast antivirus?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic yes I am. You think that is blocking the .exe?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic You sir have saved the day. I disabled the anti virus temporarily and ran the application and it worked. Seriously can not believe that was the problem! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. The same issue has been popping up all over the place ...